# unable to convert doc file to pdf file using Adobe PDF Services API

Tags: api, pdf, ms-word, adobe, doc

want to convert doc file to pdf file using [Adobe pdf service api](https://documentcloud.adobe.com/document-services/index.html#get-createPDF-status:%7E:text=tables%20and%20figures-,Create,-%3A)

Long story short it has two parts:

1. make a post request ( providing require parameters  ) and from header take x-request-id
2. make a get request ( providing require parameters  ) and as responce you will get your pdf documet

it is working fine for docx to pdf, but for doc to pdf it is showing this responce instead of pdf document

```
{
"cpf:inputs": {
    "documentIn": {
        "cpf:location": "InputFile0",
        "dc:format": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
    }
},
"cpf:engine": {
    "repo:assetId": "urn:aaid:cpf:Service-1538ece....caac2a07799503a430"
},
"cpf:status": {
    "completed": true,
    "type": "",
    "title": "For application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document mime-type The input file appears to be corrupted and cannot be processed.; transactionId=XcYuSVqy7s80GL897ZHhQGU5nEl0D5Xp",
    "status": 400,
    "report": "{\"error_code\":\"CORRUPT_DOCUMENT\"}"
 }
}
```

PS1 - i tryed d/f -2 doc files but not working for any of that.

PS2 - in document it is saying that this api can convert doc to pdf [click here](https://opensource.adobe.com/pdfservices-java-sdk-samples/apidocs/latest/com/adobe/pdfservices/operation/pdfops/CreatePDFOperation.SupportedSourceFormat.html#DOC:%7E:text=bmp%22%20media%20type-,DOC,-public%20static%20final) to see documentation.